# Detecting cancellation of a paypal billing agreement setup with reference transactions

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using the 'reference transactions' of the Paypal express checkout api to set up a recurring billing scenario for our customers. I have chosen this method since the amount billed per month will vary and there is no initial payment when entering into the billing agreement.

**My question is, can I use the paypal IPN to detect when the user cancels this?** I know that if the customer enters into this agreement they have the power to log into their own Paypal account and cancel the agreement. What variables should I be listening for through the IPN?

Whilst I see mention of recurring payments and recurring payment profiles in the IPN documentation these are not actually the same as setting up a recurring billing scenario via reference transactions (recurring payments and reference transactions are in two different parts of the general paypal api documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Enable IPN in your PayPal account , then PayPal will notify you via IPN about the Billing agreement cancel from the customer.

Answer (score 0):

If you include IPN with SetExpressCheckout, it will not work with Reference Transaction. You need to Enable IPN on PayPal site.